# Splitting text in C# by tag

Tags: c#, html

I am splitting string in my code like this:

```
var lines = myString == null 
            ? new string[] { } 
            : myString.Split(new[] { "\n", "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The trouble is this, sometimes the text looks like this:

```
sdjkgjkdgjk<br />asdfsdg
```

And in this case my code works. however, other times, the text looks like this:

```
sdjkgjkdgjk<br style="someAttribute: someProperty;"/>asdfsdg
```

And in this case, I don't get the result I want. how to split this string by the whole br tag, along with its all attributes?

Comment: Don't parse HTML with string methods or regex, use an available html parser like [HtmlAgilityPack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). How do you want to split a table or wrapped by style-sheets(f.e. word-wrap:break-word)?

Comment: Is it always valid html? If so i agree with @TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex.Split()`. Below is an example:-

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "sdjkgjkdgjk<br />asdfsdg";
        string pattern = "<br.*\\/>";            // Split on <br/>

        DisplayByRegex(input, pattern);
        input = "sdjkgjkdgjk<br style=\"someAttribute: someProperty;\"/>asdfsdg";
        DisplayByRegex(input, pattern);
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void DisplayByRegex(string input, string pattern)
    {
        string[] substrings = Regex.Split(input, pattern);
        foreach (string match in substrings)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}'", match);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope the following code will help you.

```
    var items = Regex.Split("sdjkgjkdgjk<br style='someAttribute: someProperty;'/>asdfsdg", @"<.*?>");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to split by `br` tags and newline, regex is a good option:

```
var lines = myString == null ?
    new string[] { } :
    Regex.Split(myString, "(<br.+>)|(\r\n?|\n)");
```

But if your requirements get more complex, I'd suggest using an HTML parser.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
var parts = Regex.Split(value, @"(<b>[\s\S]+?<\/b>)").Where(l => l != string.Empty).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You shoul use a regular expression.
Here you can find a [good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial) for your purpose.